# Only keep items that match string in array in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a very large array, similar to this one:

```
{
   "name":"latest_test",
   "value":[
      {
         "name":"2016-06-27-12Z",
         "type":"Folder"
      },
      {
         "name":"2016-06-28-00Z",
         "type":"Folder"
      },
      {
         "name":"2016-06-28-12Z",
         "type":"Folder"
      },
      {
         "name":"2016-06-29-00Z",
         "type":"Folder"
      },
      {
         "name":"2016-06-29-12Z",
         "type":"Folder"
      }
   ]
}
```

I only want to keep the items that have `2016-06-29` in their name. Such that I have a new array that only consists of `2016-06-29-00Z` and `2016-06-29-12Z`.

I tried to use a filter with `@contains(item(), '2016-06-29')` but this returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item() is the entire object for an element in the array.  In order to filter on a property have to specify the property also.

Change the filter condition to

```
@contains(item().name, '2016-06-29')
```